# How to match two values in two dataframe based on value Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df1

| A | b |
| --- | --- |
| foo | 121513651715123317771685 |
| etc.. | etc.. |

df2

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| nan | 1215 |
| nan | 1365 |
| nan | 1715 |
| nan | 1233 |
| nan | 1777 |
| nan | 1685 |
| etc.. | etc.. |

output

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| foo | 1215 |
| foo | 1365 |
| foo | 1715 |
| foo | 1233 |
| foo | 1777 |
| foo | 1685 |
| etc.. | etc.. |

I have broken down the values for df1['b'] by every 4th value, for df2 how can I use the values in df2['b'] to get the row value of df1['a'] based on df1['b']?

Comment: are you sure these 4-digit codes are going to be unique across different values of column A?

Comment: @PaulH, Thank you for the comment I have made changes to the question

Comment: that doesn't answer my question. what happens in df1 if A "bar" and b = "45621215..." and now you have two possible values for B = "1215"?

Comment: Basically, I  don't think you should be using dataframes here. I would take your `df1`, convert to a dictionary with column A as the keys, and process in the data in plain python from there

Comment: If df2['b'] were unique values would you still recommend use of dictionary instead of dataframes?

Comment: I can't say, because it's still not clear what you're actually trying to achieve. A dictionary might not be optimal, but I need more context to understand the end goal.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.